# regex match previous word

Tags: regex

I want to match word (numbering) before `</FORMAT>` in sentences.
The numbering has `.` It also has sub numbering such as `1.1.1.` and always ended with `.`.

For example:

> Sample1 `1.</FORMAT>`

> Sample2 `1.1.</FORMAT>`

> Sample3 `output3</FORMAT>` //match output3 correctly

sample 1 should match `1.`. Sample2 should match `1.1.`

I could not match the words if have `.`. Without `.`, can match previous word.

```
\w+(?=<\/FORMAT>)
```

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/8qVcaZ/1)

Comment: What, if anything, comes before `1.` (in sample 1) and before `1.1.` (in sample 2) and before `output3` (in sample 3) ? Also, you should post the regex that you tried in the question (because the link may disappear).

Comment: `firstword output3</FORMAT>` should just return output3. That means return last word before `</FORMAT>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

```
\w+(?:\.\w+)*\.?(?=<\/FORMAT>)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:\.\w+)*` Optionally repeat matching `.` and again 1+ word characters
- `\.?` Match an optional dot
- `(?=<\/FORMAT>)` Positive lookahead to assert `</FORMAT>` to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL9H1T/1)

Or starting the match with a word character, followed by optional word characters or dots:

```
\w[\w.]*(?=<\/FORMAT>)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TEthkH/1)